# Expandable mobile menu with plus and minus I need to make it looks nice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check my fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2287/

This is how it looks right now. I need help in making the plus and minus using css instead of "+" and "-" and also when you click plus sign it will collapse and the plus will became a minus.

Also I need help in aligning the element that has a submenu in this case it's "services"

```
function mobileMenu() {
var mobileMenu = jQuery('#mobile-menu');
var body = jQuery('body');
var mobileSubMenuTogglers = mobileMenu.find('.menu-item-has-children');
var mobileSubMenus = mobileMenu.find('.sub-menu');

jQuery('.menu-icon').on('click', function(){
    mobileMenu.toggleClass('active');
    body.toggleClass('no-scroll');
});

jQuery('#mobile-menu .menu-item-has-children').each(function(){
    var menuElement = jQuery(this);
    var subMenu = menuElement.find('.sub-menu');
    var subMenuToggleElement = jQuery('<span class="toggle-sub-menu"><span class="line line-one">-</span><span class="line line-two">+</span></span>');

    subMenu.before(subMenuToggleElement);

    mobileSubMenuTogglers.on('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2288/)***

Add with toggle function in `+&-`

```
 $('.line-one,.line-two').toggle()
```

And add default hidden in `-`  `style="display:none;">`

```
var subMenuToggleElement = jQuery('<span class="toggle-sub-menu"><span class="line line-one" style="display:none;">-</span><span class="line line-two">+</span></span>');
```